# LinqToTwitter BeginAuthorizationAsync throws NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-twitter

I am attempting to add twitter integration into an existing MVC4 Application using the LinqToTwitter nuget plugin (v3.1.2), and following the documentation [here](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Implementing-OAuth-for-ASP.NET-MVC)

```
Imports LinqToTwitter

Public Class OAuthController
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Async Function BeginAsync() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ActionResult)
    Dim auth = New MvcAuthorizer() With { _
        .CredentialStore = New SessionStateCredentialStore() With { _
            .ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerKey"), _
            .ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerSecret") _
        } _
    }

    Dim twitterCallbackUrl As String = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("Begin", "Complete")
    Dim callbackUrl = New Uri(twitterCallbackUrl)
    Return Await auth.BeginAuthorizationAsync(callbackUrl)
End Function
```

The second to final line throws a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception as the error is thrown from the plugin i am unsure how to proceed.

Stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/970aea58edf6836ca8c3)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The root cause is because the BeginAuthorizationAsync uses HttpContext.Current under the covers, which is not the correct way to access the context for MVC Controllers.

I've submitted a pull request here: https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/pull/18

As a workaround you can add the following code just before calling BeginAuthorizationAsync.

```
auth.GoToTwitterAuthorization = (authUrl) => {
    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(authUrl);
};
```